# Unable to parse parameter: promoteorqurantineFunctionName

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, cloud-security

I'm deploying an Azure function app as a part of security implementation into and I'm getting the above mentioned error as mentioned in Title section. Here is the powershell script i am running

> az deployment group create 
> --name fss-promote-or-quarantine-plugin-deployment 
> --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME 
> --template-uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/trendmicro/cloudone-filestorage
> plugins/master/post-scan-actions/azure-python-promote-or-quarantine/template.json 
> -p promoteOrQuarantineFunctionName=$FUNCTION_NAME 
> scanningStorageAccountResourceID=$BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_ID 
> scanResultTopicResourceID=$SCAN_RESULT_TOPIC_RESOURCE_ID 
> promoteStorageAccountConnectionString="$PROMOTE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTION_STRING" 
> promoteMode=move 
> quarantineStorageAccountConnectionString="$QUARANTINE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTION_STRING" 
> quarantineMode=move

Screenshot of the error that I'm getting:
[image: Screenshot of Error that i am getting]

Comment: The code in the screenshot is not the code you've posted in above?

Comment: Hello Mathias, its similar, I have just added the subscription id, and other required fields into the screenshot.

Comment: There's a big difference - in the screenshot you have spaces between the parameter names and arguments. Try with `--parameters promoteFunctionName=nameOfFunction` instead of `--parameters promoteFunctionName = nameOfFunction`

Comment: Thanks Mathias, it worked!!, edited for other fields as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried by giving the space between the parameter names and values and it given the same error:

[image]

This cmdlet creates the storage account, taken from the [GitHub ARM](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli.md#deploy-remote-template) Article.

As @Mathias R. Jessen said, there should be no space between the parameter names and arguments passed in the CLI Cmdlets:

[image: enter link description here]
[image: enter link description here]